# What Does The MAE Actually Telling me?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I've created a simple linear regression model to predict S&P 500 closing prices. then calculated the Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and got an MAE score of 1290. Now, I don't want to know if this is right or wrong but I want to know what MAE of 1290 is telling me about my model.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be honest "in general" it tells you nearly nothing. The value is quite arbitrary, and only if you understand exactly your data you can draw any conclusions.

MAE stands for Mean Absolute Error, thus if yours is 1290 it means, that if you randomly choose a data point from your data, then, you would expect your prediction to be 1290 away from the true value. Is it good? Bad? Depends on the scale of your output. If it is in millions, then the error this big is nothing, and the model is good. If your output values are in the range of thousands, this is horrible.

If I understand correctly S&P 500 closing prices are numbers between 0 and 2500 (for last 36 years), thus error of 1290 looks like your model learned nothing. This is pretty much like a constant model, always answering "1200" or something around this value.

Comment: Could we use MAE to tell us the probability we will get an answer wrong? So for example if my scale is -1, 0 and 1 and a classifier has an MAE of 0.2, could I say that of a sample of 20 predicted outcomes 4 would be incorrect?

Comment: No, MAE has nothing to do with probability, it is a regression metric and as such should be used for regression tasks. For classification (problem where "correct answer" makes sense) use classification metrics (like accuracy, which is literally probability you are asking about)

Answer (score 3):

MAE obtained with a model should always be verified against a baseline model.

A frequently used baseline is median value assignment. Calculate the MAE for the case when all your predictions are always equal to the median of your target variable vector, then see for yourself if your model's MAE is significantly below that. If it is — congrats.

Note that, in this case the baseline MAE will depend on the target distribution. If your test sample contains lots of instances that are really close to the median, then it will be almost impossible to get a model with a MAE better than the baseline. Thus, MAE should only be used when your test sample is sufficiently diverse. In the extreme case of only 1 instance in the test sample you will get the baseline MAE=0, which will always be no worse than any model you may come up with.

This issue with MAE is especially notable, when you get a MAE for your total sample and then want to check how it changes across different subsamples. Say, you have a model that predicts yearly income based on education, age, marital status etc. You get a MAE of $1.2k, the baseline MAE is $5k, so you conclude that your model is pretty good. Then you want to check how the model deals with bottom-earners and get a MAE of $1.7k with a baseline of $0.5k. The same is likely to occur, if you inspect the errors in the 18-22yo demographics.